# removing Objects from an event in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So I'm creating a game where an enemy is firing a bullet.  The bullet eventrully hits a collision I made, when it hits the end of the screen.  Im wanting at this point to remove it and clear the address back to a nil value.  When checking the address before and after the collision, no change was made.  please help with any insight you might have on this.

```
local onCollision = function(event)
        if event.phase == "began" then
            event.object2:removeSelf();
            event.object2 = nil;
        end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("collision",onCollision);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local onCollision = function(event)
        if event.phase == "began" then
            event.target:removeSelf();
            event.target= nil;
        end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("collision",onCollision);
```